# how to select join subquery using laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how to select join subquery using laravel query builder

sql select statement

```
SELECT  product_name.name
    , product_price.weight
FROM    product_price
LEFT JOIN product_name
    ON (SELECT product_price.product_code
        FROM product_price
        LEFT JOIN product_name
            ON  product_price.product_code = product_name.code
        WHERE product_price.barcode = '1234567890'
    )
```

How to convert sql select statement to Laravel query builder?

Comment: You can use eloquent.

Comment: The query appears to be nonsense. What are you actually trying to do - and why do you have separate tables for product names and product prices?